# Unable to call two ajax methods in a window.addEvent('load', function())

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have two `AJAX` method (`get_partenaire_convention()` and `get_partenaire_contact()`) both method call the Joomla controler and fill a html table

I added this two methods like this

```
window.addEvent(\'load\', function() {
    get_partenaire_convention();
    get_partenaire_contact();     
});'
```

The result is bad,
I have a table convetion filled with data and the other not,when I change the order  of the methode call and I put the `get_partenaire_contact()` first I got the table contact filled and the other not.

I think the problem is with asynchronous call of the AJAX.

This is the ajax call

```
function get_partenaire_convention()
    {
        var id_partenaire = document.getElementById("jform_id").value;
        document.getElementById('ajax-partenaire_convention-image_loader').innerHTML = '<img src="components/com_tktransit/images/ajax-loader.gif" width="16" height="16"/>';

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        else
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("convention_table").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById('ajax-partenaire_convention-image_loader').innerHTML = '<img src="components/com_tktransit/images/ajax-blanc.gif"/>';                        
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","index.php?option=com_tktransit&task=partenaire.get_partenaire_convention&id_partenaire="+id_partenaire, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
```

Comment: what is with the `\'`?

Comment: Can we see these AJAX methods? They are probably conflicting, erasing each other's HTML.

Comment: @epascarello because of this $document = & JFactory::getDocument();
    $js = '
    window.addEvent(\'load\', function() {
        get_partenaire_convention();
        get_partenaire_contact();
       
              });
            ';
    $document->addScriptDeclaration($js);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
```

is a global variable

If the other method is global, it will override it.

```
var xmlhttp;  //define it so it is not a global
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
else
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

Comment: Niiice,that's it. See a small variable blow evrything. Thank you : )